# Change nth-child native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I change the number in the nth-child brackets on click? e.g. I click a button and the next page of a slideshow comes up.

```
.slideshow:nth-child(n){}
```

I want to change n. I am using native JavaScript only.

Comment: you really ought to show some code if you want to get meaningful help.

Comment: Please send some sample code, its very difficult to understand this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var n = 0;
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
n= 2
document.querySelector('.you-elemnt:nth-child('+n+')').style.display = 'inline';
});
```

this is just an example you can make it more dynamic by changing `data-` of that button whenever its click and also use it to show your slides dynamically.

Comment: I ended up just using an array